# The request was aborted could not create ssl/tls secure channel. httpwebrequest

Tags: ssl

I'm using an approach I found on Google that does not work as I hoped.

```
 string resultxml = string.Empty;
 #region First Link code
 try
 {
     ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
     ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
     HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

     //Header Settings
     req.Method = "POST"; // Post method
     req.ContentType = "text/xml";// content type
     req.KeepAlive = false;
     req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
     //Certificate with private key
     String certificateFileNameWithPath = "C:\\JPCertificates\\test.pfx";
     String certificatePassword = "password";
     X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificateFileNameWithPath, certificatePassword);
     req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
     req.PreAuthenticate = true;
     String XML = Xml;// "Test Message";//reader.ReadToEnd();
     byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);
     req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
     // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
     Stream writer = req.GetRequestStream();
     // Write the XML text into the stream
     writer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     writer.Close();
     WebResponse rsp = req.GetResponse();
     StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());

     #endregion
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     throw ex;
 }
 return resultxml;

 //Send the SOAP message StreamWriter stm = new    StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8); 
stm.Write(requestXML); 
stm.Flush(); 
stm.Close();
```

```
//Send the SOAP message StreamWriter stm = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8); 
stm.Write(requestXML); 
stm.Flush(); 
stm.Close();
```

Comment: //Send the SOAP message
                StreamWriter stm = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                stm.Write(requestXML);
                stm.Flush();
                stm.Close();

Comment: //Send the SOAP message
                StreamWriter stm = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                stm.Write(requestXML);
                stm.Flush();
                stm.Close();

Comment: As it stands now the question is badly formatted, the problem is not clearly shown and you've put some stuff into comments instead of the question where the relation to the question is not even clear. If you expects others to invest their free time to help you it would be better if you clearly show your problem, use proper formatting and put all needed information into the question. Also, show what you've tried and where you've failed instead of just claiming that some unspecified stuff you've found on google did not help.